# uitableview return 2 cellIdentifier

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

[image]

I have two cells:

like taskcella, taskcellb

but it dynamically returns only 1 cell data

is there possible to add and return multiple cellidentifiers?

```
 public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
          // in a Storyboard, Dequeue will ALWAYS return a cell, 
          UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
          cell.TextLabel.Text = "Görev : " + tableItemsX[indexPath.Row].Gorev;

          UITableViewCell celld = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifierd);
          celld.TextLabel.Text = "İşlem : " + tableItemsX[indexPath.Row].Gorev;
          return celld;    return cell;
        }
```

this is code which return first, returns first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that in you `TableViewSource` you override method `RowsInSection` and it's returns `2`

```
    public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return 2;
    }
```

Then rewrite you `GetCell` method in the next way

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if (indexPath.Row == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
        cell.TextLabel.Text = "Görev : " + tableItemsX[indexPath.Row].Gorev;

        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        UITableViewCell celld = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifierd);
        celld.TextLabel.Text = "İşlem : " + tableItemsX[indexPath.Row].Gorev;

        return celld;    
    }
}
```

Comment: got one simple question, is it possible to add little thumb picture to left? in this line?

Comment: use `cell.ImageView` to set image